# Router Link tag breaking my Vue application

Tags: vue.js, components, vue-router

The Vue component in question (House) is responsible for rendering different types of houses that are simple javascript objects. It differentiates between two types of houses: those created by the user (`madeByMe: true`) and those got from the API (`madeByMe: false`). It uses a conditional (v-if/v-else) to render different content based on this property both of these kind of houses have. The issue arises when a router-link that redirects the user to a detail page is added around an img tag inside the v-else block, causing unexpected rendering behavior and an error related to a missing "id" parameter. Basically, the rendering goes further than expected, triggering an error related to a missing "id" parameter.

This issue occurs even though the router-link is inside an else statement that should only be reached to render houses that I get from the API (not the ones created by the user). If I remove the router link everything works as it should, the house component renders only the house created by the user. If I add it back the house component tries to render the div with the v-else tag even though it should not and I get the error regarding the missing id parameter. Of course I cannot access that id parameter but I shouldn't be able to render that part of the component in the first place.

Here's the code of the component in question:

```html
<template>
    <!-- Basic house component that will be rendered every time you see 
        an house listing in the application -->
    <div v-if="house" class="houses">
        <!-- If the madeByMe property is true im gonna rendere the data of the houses im 
            creating, otherwise ill just render the data of the houses from the api-->

        <div v-if="house && house.madeByMe">
            <h1>{{ house.city }}</h1>
            <h1>{{ house.street }}</h1>
            <img :src="imageUrl ? imageUrl : (house.image ? house.image : 'default-image-url')" alt="House Image">
            <h1>{{ house.number }}</h1>
            <h1>{{ house.addition }}</h1>
            <h1>{{ house.postalCode }}</h1>
            <h1>{{ house.price }}</h1>
            <h1>{{ house.size }}</h1>
            <h1>{{ house.garage }}</h1>
            <h1>{{ house.bedrooms }}</h1>
            <h1>{{ house.bathrooms }}</h1>
            <h1>{{ house.constructionDate }}</h1>
            <h1>{{ house.details }}</h1>

        </div>

        <div v-else class="api-houses">
            <div v-if="house" class="api-house">

                <router-link :to='{ name: "house-details", params: { id: house.id } }'>
                    <img :src="house.image" class="house-image">
                </router-link>


                <!-- this button fires the toggle like function that handles the functionality
            to store the liked houses and render them in the favorites section -->

                <div class="api-house-info">

                    <div class="house-address">
                        <h1>{{ house.location ? house.location.street : '' }}</h1>
                        <h1>{{ house.location ? house.location.houseNumber : '' }}</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="price">
                        <img :src="price" class="icon">
                        <p>{{ house.price }}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="zip-city">
                        <p>{{ house.location ? house.location.zip : '' }}</p>
                        <p>{{ house.location ? house.location.city : '' }}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="rooms">

                        <div class="bed">
                            <img :src="bed" class="icon">
                            <p>{{ house.rooms ? house.rooms.bedrooms : '' }}</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="bath">
                            <img :src="bath" class="icon">
                            <p>{{ house.rooms ? house.rooms.bathrooms : '' }}</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="size">
                            <img :src="size" class="icon">
                            <p>{{ house.size }} m2</p>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <button @click="toggleLike">Like</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

```js
<script>

import FavoritesList from '@/views/FavoritesList.vue';
import Bath from "@/assets/ic_bath@3x.png"
import Bed from "@/assets/ic_bed@3x.png"
import Size from "@/assets/ic_size@3x.png"
import Price from "@/assets/ic_price@3x.png"

export default {
    data() {
        return {

            bath: Bath,
            bed: Bed,
            size: Size,
            price: Price,

        }
    },
    // these are the props that im going to get from the parent components, 
    //I just need an house object and a url for the image
    props: {
        house: {
            type: Object,
            required: true,
        },

        imageUrl: {
            type: String,
            default: "", // Set a default value or leave it as an empty string
        },

    },

    computed: {
        liked() {
            return this.$store.state.myFavoriteHouses.includes(this.house.id);
        },
    },

    methods: {
        toggleLike() {
            this.$store.dispatch('toggleLike', this.house.id);
            console.log("clicked")
        },
    },

    mounted() {
        // Logs the received props to the console
        console.log('Received props in House component:', this.house);
    },

    components: { FavoritesList }
}

</script>
```

I dont know if it helps but this is the myHouse component that tries to access the House component above to render the details of the house created by the user

```html
<template> 
<!-- This component renders the info regarding the user's create house. Here the user
can then choose to either delete or edit his/her house -->
  <div>
    <button @click="goToEditPage">edit</button>
    <button @click="showDeletionConfirm">Delete</button>
    <DeletionConfirmPopup v-if="showPopup" @confirmed="deleteHouse" @canceled="cancelDeletion"></DeletionConfirmPopup>
    
    <House :house="house" :imageUrl="imageUrl"></House>
  </div>
</template>
```

```js
<script>
import DeletionConfirmPopup from './DeletionConfirmPopup.vue';
import House from './House.vue';

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      house: {},
      imageUrl: null,
      showPopup: false
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    /* as soon as the components is mounted im getting the house's infos in order to render them*/
    const houseIndex = this.$route.params.index;
    console.log('House index:', houseIndex);
    const selectedHouse = this.$store.state.myListings[houseIndex];
    if (selectedHouse) {
      this.house = selectedHouse;
      this.loadImage();
    }
    else {
      // Handle the case where the house is not found, e.g., redirect to an error page
      console.error(`House at index ${houseIndex} not found.`);
    }
  },
  methods: {
    //this function handles the reading of the house's picture
    loadImage() {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = () => {
        this.imageUrl = reader.result;
      };
      
      reader.readAsDataURL(this.house.image);
    },

    //these functions handle the editing and deletion functionalities, respectively
    goToEditPage() {
      const index = this.$store.state.myListings.length - 1;
      // Redirect to the details page with the index as a parameter
      this.$router.push({ name: "edit-house", params: { index } });
    },
    deleteHouse() {
      const index = this.$store.state.myListings.length - 1;
      this.$store.dispatch("deleteHouse", index);
      this.showPopup = false;
      this.$router.push({ name: "home"});
    },
    showDeletionConfirm() {
      // Set showPopup to true to display the popup
      this.showPopup = true;
    },
    cancelDeletion() {
      this.showPopup=false;
    }
  },
  components: { DeletionConfirmPopup, House }
}

</script>
```

I'm not a native English speaker so if I explained myself like crap let me know and I'll try to do better